# Global variable in C#

Tags: c#, global-variables

I want to use some global variables in my program. Do we have anything which could help directly define global variables as we have #define in C++.

For Eg: Say I have the below mentioned global variables in C++:

```
#define CROSSOVER_RATE            0.7
#define MUTATION_RATE             0.001
#define POP_SIZE                  100        
#define CHROMO_LENGTH             300
#define GENE_LENGTH               4
#define MAX_ALLOWABLE_GENERATIONS   400
```

I wish to define these in my C# program as global variables only. Please let me know how can I do it?

Comment: By the way, that’s bad C++ code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: and that's unhelpful criticism.

Comment: you should avoid global variables --- it's bad practice

Comment: @IgbyLargeman Since this is a particularly outdated idiom the only real advice I can give here is to read a modern C++ book. I could point out that using macros here has no benefit and lots of drawbacks (which doesn’t really explain anything! Comments are too short), but this would probably be a drop on a hot stone.

Comment: Minor thing, but #defines are not global *variables*; they're compile-time constants.  It's a convenience equivalent to hard-coding the values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define them inside a class:

```
public static class Constants {
  public const double CrossoverRate = 0.7;
  ...
}
```

Use them like this: `Constants.CrossoverRate`.

But I'd only do that if they were *really* constant, like [PI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi.aspx). For parameters that can change, I'd prefer using a class with instance-level values. I think you'll want this kind of flexibility to tune your genetic algorithm, or to use more than one parameter-set at once. This is one way to do it (immutable class):

```
public class GeneticAlgorithmParameters {

  public double CrossoverRate { get; private set; }
  ...

  public GenericAlgorithmParameters(double crossoverRate, ... others) {
    CrossoverRate = crossoverRate;
    ...
  }

}
```

Now you pass an instance of `GeneticAlgorithmParameters` to your `GeneticAlgorithm` class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string MyConstant = "constantValue";
}
```

You call them as follows:

```
public void MyMethod
{
    var string = Constants.MyConstant;
}
```

Comment: can you use "string" as a variable name in C#?

Comment: @jb: only with an @ in front: `@string`.