# How to declare a global integer variable in ASP.Net Core and Implement it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-variables

Making a global integer variable and implement it in Asp.net Core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238037/global-variable-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `static` class with `static` int variable like this

```
public static class GlobalVariables {
    public static int OnlineUser { get; set; }
}
```

You can use anywhere use want example

```
public ActionResult Index(){
     GlobalVariables.OnlineUser += 1;
}
```